# Update string from a cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this variable in my script to find a doc ID in my Drive to auto-populate the same doc with some placeholders inside it. How to update this value (the ID) in the script dinamically from a cell in my sheet, that I could change with the ID I desire without update the script manually?

The string:

```
var TEMPLATE_ID = 'xxxxxxxxx';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to take the value straight from a sheet, you should use the the `getValue()` method like this instead:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID_OF_THE_SS").getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME");
var TEMPLATE_ID = ss.getRange("RANGE_OF_THE_ID").getValue();
```

Moreover, you can also make use of Apps Script triggers in order to monitor the changes directly.

**Reference**

- [SpreadsheetApp Class Apps Script - openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid);
- [Sheet Class Apps Script - getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns);
- [Range Class Apps Script - getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue);
- [Apps Script Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers);
- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

Comment: And so if I would to take the ID from Cell C2?

Comment: It would be `getRange("C2")`.

Comment: I have this error: TypeError:Cannot read property 'getRange' of null

Comment: Did you change the "SHEET_NAME" with the name of your sheet?

Comment: now I have this error "ReferenceError: TEMPLATE_ID is not defined"

Comment: P.s. can I share the script?

Comment: If you copied my answer, then your variable is called `TEMPLATED_ID` and not `TEMPLATE_ID`. I will update my answer to reflect the original name of **your** variable.